# jquery Drop-down menu

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find/make a good jquery drop-down menu with animation (fadein/fadeout or slidedown) that activates on hover, not click.

What do you recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the original plugins out there... [Superfish](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Superfish).